# cocoapods activesupport conflicts ios development

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, cocoapods, activesupport

I tried reporting this issue on the cocoapods project but was directed to post here.  I recently took on a project where I work and I am having trouble getting what the previous consultant setup to function on my local workstation.  I was able to successfully install the cocoapods gem, however, when I run `pod install` it blows up....

```
specification.rb:1990:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate xcodeproj-0.14.1, because activesupport-4.0.0.rc1 conflicts with activesupport (~> 3.0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1163:in `activate'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1199:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1185:in `each'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1185:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1167:in `activate'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:48:in `gem'
    from /Users/chrishough/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

I currently use rbenv with ruby 2.0.0 and the latest editions of xcode, git, etc.  All of my ruby and rails projects are working fine, but I am a bit of a noob to ios.

Thoughts? Pointers?

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1775
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1762

Comment: It looks like a gem dependency conflict with your ruby environment. Maybe you could try installing a fresh version of ruby w/ rbenv and only install the  cocoapods gem. Or try uninstalling the offending gem from the current version of ruby. Or you could try using bundler  and then run `bundle exec pod install`.

Comment: @JimJeffers that worked, see the answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @jimjeffers comment above, I had to switch to a different version of Ruby 2.0 installed, in this case "2.0.0-p195" and `run rbenv local 2.0.0-p195` => after follow the steps on http://cocoapods.org/ running:

```
gem install cocoapods
pod install
```

and once completed I was able to startup the ios project.