# Error when trying to release private pod: Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate cocoapods-0.33.1, because activesupport-4.0.2

Tags: rubygems, rake, cocoapods

When running `rake release` with a Rakefile generated by Cocoapods to release a version of my private pod I get the following error:

```
Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate cocoapods-0.33.1, because activesupport-4.0.2 conflicts with activesupport (< 4, >= 3.2.15)
```

I understand that there seems to be a dependency conflict, but don't know how to resolve it. I tried uninstalling cocoapods (with `gem cleanup cocoapods` and `gem uninstall cocoapods`) and tried removing old versions of other gems with `gem cleanup` (which seemed to delete a lot of stuff). But that didn't help.

Also, since I'm not actually doing ruby development but just use the generated rake file to release a cocoa pod, I don't think that [Bundler](http://bundler.io) would help me, or does it?

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I would also be interested in an answer to that question. I'm in the exact same situation using the Rakefile generated by "pod lib create". I tried removing old versions of the activesupport gem but it seems that cocoapods depends on 4.x while xcodeproj (a cocoapods dependency) depends on 3.x; reinstalling the cocoapods gem brings back activesupport 3.x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cocoapods activesupport conflicts ios development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465696/cocoapods-activesupport-conflicts-ios-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to downgrade the version of activesupport.

Run `gem uninstall activesupport` and delete any versions that are >= 4. If you had a valid previous version installed already then you should be good to go.

If you don't run `gem install activesupport --version 3.2.18` to get a valid version.